# Does Windows Vista create any record when inserting blank CD/DVD into the drive?

Tags: windows

When inserting a blank CD/DVD does Vista make any record (e.g. in registry?) that it happened? If one inserted 3 CDs/DVDs, one by one, on the assumption that Vista creates these records, would there be one or three records (one - if records are overwritten)?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question? Please look in the event log.

Comment: The question is _not_ the same... BTW - Event Log, but which section and what event ID?

Comment: Sigh. Look in the event logs to see if there is an event created. Look in the registry to see if there is an entry created. [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) will monitor for registry changes.

Comment: Answering this question would also be very useful: How many discs, in general, a given Windows Vista user has burnt? I'm thinking about a number which shows a number of discs a user has burnt on his account since the date that account was created.

Comment: @DavidPostill - OK, I'll check these things. In case of not finding any answers I'll update my post.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer that (in general). Whay do you want to know anyway? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: User's account is relatively new and I know the number of discs burnt (I've got these discs). I'm trying to check if the number of discs I've got is the same as the number of discs burnt by the user. BTW - no logs in the Event Viewer. Regarding ProcessMonitor - does it show registry changes from the days before it was run? Mine shows only today's changes...

Comment: No - it starts logging from when your run it. So run it, burn a CD and see what happens.

Comment: OK, thank you, I understand now, BUT when I run ProcessMonitor the number of events increases and increases and increases... How can I stop that to be able to monitor just what happens when starting a DVD burning program and burning a DVD?

Comment: I found a much easier way to monitor registry changes - [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html), otherwise you can use the filtering options in Process Monitor.

Comment: OK, I'll try to employ RegFromApp and inform about results so other people having the same issue can find the answer very quickly.

Comment: The first observation (without burning a disc) regarding explorer.exe is as follows (burning program is BurnAware Free): 1. When running burnaware.exe this is what RegFromApp (RFA) shows: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SessionInformation]
"ProgramCount"=dword:00000005; 2. When clicking "Burn a data disc" datadisc.exe is run and RFA shows: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SessionInformation]
"ProgramCount"=dword:00000006

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{volume_id}]
"Generation"=dword:000000b0;

Comment: 3. When closing "Data disc window" RFA shows: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SessionInformation]
"ProgramCount"=dword:00000005

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{volume_id}]
"Generation"=dword:000000b1; 4. When BurnAware is closed RFA shows only this: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{volume_id}]
"Generation"=dword:000000b1; Any comments, suggestions on that? To be frank I'm not good at interpreting registry records.

Comment: The timeline for this is as follows: 1. Executing BurnAware (burnaware.exe); 2. Choosing an option -> "Burn a data disc" (datadisc.exe) (now one can add some files to be burnt, but in this example I don't do it); 3. I simply close "Data disc window"; 4. Then I close BurnAware.

Comment: Unfortunately when reseting PC "Generation"=dword:000000b1 is reseted...

Answer (score 0):

It logs hardware actions, for example it logs when you open the lid. It doesn't log whether you put in a blank or whatever CD. After you put in a CD it also logs u closed the lid.

Comment: Do you mean Event Log/ Hardware Events?